# Using backbone.js, detect radio button event and show or hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm using a backbone view to capture when a user chooses between two radio buttons.

Here is what the radio buttons look like:

```
Do you have a spouse?
[ ] Yes
[ ] No
```

And the HTML:

```
<span>Do you have a spouse?</span>
<input type="radio" name="hasSpouse" value="yes">Yes
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="hasSpouse" value="no">No

<div class="hasSpouseYes" style="display:none;">Awesome!</div>
<div class="hasSpouseNo"  style="display:none;">That's too bad</div>
```

Two divs are either shown or hidden depending on whether the user clicks the 'yes' or the 'no' radio button.

So I put this is the event section of the view:

```
'click input[name=hasSpouse]:checked': 'hasSpouseEvent',
```

And here is the function that is supposed to take care of hiding and show the various div sections.

```
 hasSpouseEvent: function () {
        var val = $('input[name=hasSpouse]:checked').val();
        if (val === 'yes') {
            this.$('.hasSpouseYes').show();
            this.$('.hasSpouseNo').hide();
        } else {
            this.$('.hasSpouseYes').hide();
            this.$('.hasSpouseNo').show();
        }
 }
```

The first time, it works fine.  But after testing it out and clicking the 'yes' and 'no' radio buttons, it starts seemingly randomly showing and hiding either div.

Comment: I just fiddled it and it works fine I think: http://jsfiddle.net/mmem37ys/1/

Comment: When the user selects no, we should display `Awesome!`, correct..? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A radio button is checked when it is clicked.
The selector you are using to bind the event and access the value is `'input[name=hasSpouse]:checked'`

In a way of thinking, the radio button becomes selected after it is clicked. So your selector shouldn't be matching. But backbone delegates event handlers to the view element. So I guess by the time event propagates till the view element, radio is marked as checked and matches the selector, hence triggering the attached handler.

Another thought is that we have an option to prevent the default behavior using `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler. So the default behavior should ideally take place after executing all the handlers. Again in this case the event is not directly attached to the element.

Due to the way of implementation you might be getting buggy behavior in some browser.

To be on the safer side it's better to use the selector `input[name="hasSpouse"]` and access the clicked element from the event object as shown below:

```js
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '#form',
   events: {
     'click input[name="hasSpouse"]': 'hasSpouseEvent',
   },
   hasSpouseEvent: function(event) {
     $this = $(event.target);
     this.$('.hasSpouseYes')[$this.val() == 'yes' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
     this.$('.hasSpouseNo')[$this.val() == 'no' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
   }
 });

 var view = new View();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="form"> <span>Do you have a spouse?</span>

  <input type="radio" name="hasSpouse" value="yes">Yes
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="hasSpouse" value="no">No
  <div class="hasSpouseYes" style="display:none;">Awesome!</div>
  <div class="hasSpouseNo" style="display:none;">That's too bad</div>
</div>
```